# How Can i print the wp_editor field content?

Tags: wp-editor

Normal editor content we can call as the_content(); here, i have 3 more wp_editor fields, how can i print the code in my page?.

```
<?php wp_editor( $holds, 'holds', $settings = array('textarea_rows'=>20) ); ?>
```

Comment: Is there any chance that you mean 'post content' by 'editor content'? In what way do you store these custom editors contents? Do you use Custom Fields or in some other way?

Comment: Hi Krzysiek Dróżdż, thank you for your replay. it's a CPT . please look this http://pastebin.com/2SRvBwrq. and solve this problem.

Comment: @ShihabMalayil Please don't post pastebin links. Update your question with your code.

Answer (score 1):

OK, since you save these additional values as Custom Fields (see your code below):

```
function save_points(){
        global $post;
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "category", $_POST["category"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "brand", $_POST["brand"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "features", $_POST["features"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "holds", $_POST["holds"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "extra", $_POST["extra"]);
}
```

You should use `[get_post_meta][1]` to get these values.

Comment: thank you <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'features', true ); ?>

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. You can also run filters on it. For example: `<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'features', true)); ?>` - pls select this as correct answer, if it was helpful.

Comment: hi Krzysiek Dróżdż, still not showing,it's worked yesterday.now i don't know what happend, field productid not saving.all custom fields not printing data on the page. cpt:http://pastebin.com/Sidr1juD template code:http://pastebin.com/MiArdFcs

Comment: If it worked, then it is correct. First bug is that on line 49 you store value as `$id` variable, but then use `$productid` (it's undefined). You should also take care of escaping values correctly. And you don't use `manage_posts_custom_column` correctly. Don't use `get_the_ID()` inside. This function takes `post_id` as second argument. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column#Examples